# JSON_SET isn't updating null JSON field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I have a nullable JSON MySQL 5.7 field which I am finding almost impossible to get working.

Example query:

`` UPDATE `json_test` SET `data` = JSON_SET(`data`, '$.a', 1) ``

If the field data is NULL already, it won't update.

If it's `{ "a" : 2 }`, then it'll update correctly to 1. I need it to set if not set already, which is what JSON_SET is supposed to do.

Any ideas what's happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's [not supposed to](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-set) work with nulls

> Otherwise, a path/value pair for a nonexisting path in the document is
>   ignored and has no effect.

Now mysql doesn't let you use a subquery on the same table that's being updated, but you could probably stil solve this with an UPDATE JOIN using CASE/WHEN but I am too lazy so I leave you with a two query solution.

```
UPDATE `json_test` SET `data` = JSON_SET(`data`, '$.a', 1) WHERE data IS NOT NULL;

UPDATE `json_test` SET `data` = JSON_OBJECT('$.a', 1) WHERE data IS NULL;
```

Comment: That's great. The only bug you have in that is JSON_OBJECT you simply set 'a', 1, you don't access using $.a as you're setting the key.

Answer (score 16):

## 1) An alternative is to check for null and return an valid empty JSON set ({}) to JSON_SET in those situations, so it just puts in the new data.

UPDATE `json_test` SET `data` = JSON_SET(IFNULL(`data`,'{}' ), '$.a', 1)

## 2) Finally, another option would be for the data specification to have a default value of {}, ex.

```
`dataJson TEXT DEFAULT '{}',`
```

I prefer the first option I presented as I like leaving fields NULL until I need them to have data but then I expect them to start packing in the JSON data immediately!

Comment: This is brilliant. Its simple trick but very very helpful. Now with this, we can simply update existing or insert a new one using JSON_SET.

Answer (score 7):

Updating the entire table for that is an overkill and changing the table definition as well.
This should have no noticeable performance impact:

```
UPDATE `json_test` SET `data` = JSON_SET(COALESCE(`data`,'{}'), '$.a', 1)
```

Explanation:
JSON_SET needs a full processing of the column in any case, so it will be evaluated for validity, parsed, etc.
The COALESCE changes a NULL field to an empty JSON object, so the json will be valid and the SET will be successful.
You probably won't be able to measure a performance difference.