# MySQL 5.7 JSON column update

Tags: mysql, json

I am using MySQL 5.7. I have a table with a JSON column.

```
MySQL [test_db]> select * from mytable;
+----+-------+---------------------+
| id | name  | hobby               |
+----+-------+---------------------+
|  1 | Rahul | {"Game": "Cricket"} |
|  2 | Sam   | null                |
+----+-------+---------------------+
```

Here, for row id = 2, I want to insert a data. I did -

```
update mytable set hobby = JSON_SET(hobby, '$.Game', 'soccer') where id = 2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

It seems like data inserted properly, But when I checked

```
MySQL [test_db]> select * from mytable;
+----+-------+---------------------+
| id | name  | hobby               |
+----+-------+---------------------+
|  1 | Rahul | {"Game": "Cricket"} |
|  2 | Sam   | null                |
+----+-------+---------------------+
```

data is not inserted, Can anybody give some hint, what I am missing here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hobby is NULL, and you can't set a property on NULL, so use an IF statement instead, to convert null to an empty object first (Or initialize hobby as an empty object instead of NULL):

```
UPDATE mytable
SET hobby = JSON_SET(IF(hobby IS NULL, '{}', hobby), '$.Game', 'soccer')
WHERE id = 2;
```

Alternatitvely, use [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
UPDATE mytable
SET hobby = JSON_SET(COALESCE(hobby, '{}'), '$.Game', 'soccer')
WHERE id = 2;
```

See dbfiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3T5qXgvir4sK9cS5vSQU4B/0).

Comment: A simple google search also yielded a ton of results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41235535/json-set-isnt-updating-null-json-field-in-mysql